# ViewPager on a Layout behind a ScrollView not listening to gestures

Tags: android, android-viewpager, scrollview

I'm struggling with a situation that I'm not being able to solve:

So, the thing is: I want a view pager on a Relative layout. Above this relative Layout I Have a scrollview that has a transparent layout to show the images of the viewpager.

The effect I wanted to achieve was : A scroll view that covers the view pager ( but being able to scroll the images ).

So, At this point I have this and isn't working:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/ScrollViewProfile"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:overScrollMode="never"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:scrollbars="none" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/scrollViewContainer"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:orientation="vertical" 
                android:clickable="true">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_marginTop="180dp"
                    android:id="@+id/layoutTransparent"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/grad_transparent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:clickable="true" >
                </LinearLayout>
<-- this drawable is an effect that gives some shadow above -->
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/profile_text_container"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="63dp" 
                    android:background="#FFFFFF">
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Could someone give me some help on this?

Comment: It is important how you handle it in code, touch events are broadcasted through view hierarchy depending on returning result from on**listeners

Comment: Are you able to scroll within the scrollview?

Comment: scrols perfectly.

The only code I'm trying to handle this is via xml, I have this feeling that in the past I've been able to set a onclicklistener on a button that had a layout above it and to use the google maps with a layout above so I taught that with a view pager and a scroll view it might be possible. It must be possible since airbnb and foursquare do it on the profiles